# Media queries with AMP for mobile webpages

Tags: html, css, amp-html

Recently, I started looking into using [AMP](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/) for my blog.

I started to read through the docs and look at some examples of it in use and it looks great and anything that improves performance, is a step in the right direction for me & I'd like to include it in my website pages.

The question I have - If I have a blog on my website at the url: `www.example.com/blog` (responsive design but looks best on desktop/laptop screens) and I'd like to use **AMP** for my mobile view, how does the browser I'm using on my phone (`safari`, `chrome`, ..) or on my computer (`chrome`, `firefox`, ..) know which page to serve up?

Does AMP recognise the width & height of your device and serve the mobile page, is there a certain viewport, that if you exceed, it will change based on that - or do you have to use `@media` queries (css link stylesheet or inline styling)?

---

**Expanding on AMP question with media queries**

Let's say I add a subdomain to my website to serve up my AMP blog - e.g. (`www.blog.example.com/`) - If I google on my phone for "example blog" will it find the mobile/desktop html views or likewise, if I google the same thing on my web browser on desktop, does it find/serve up the AMP page (`www.blog.example.com/`) or my main blog page (`www.example.com/blog`).

How does this work? And is there a preferred way to use & distinguish between AMP & normal html pages with css styling (that includes `@media` queries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating AMP page and linking with regular page you can use

```
<link rel="canonical" href="$SOME_URL">
```

pls refer https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery. Hope this help!

Comment: awh yes - so you just add a link inside the main html page to the AMP version and depending on what you're browsing on (mobile/desktop) you're served up the correct page? (recognised by google)

Comment: yes, you are right. This creates constant link with the regular page and the web crawler can use this to server AMP page based on the requesting device.

Comment: Also, is the user prompted if the visit the non-AMP page on their mobile, to switch to the mobile view? Is that how it works?

Comment: Nope, there wont be any prompt from the browser. AMP helps the device to load page faster and use little device resource. Along with improved search results.

Answer (score 1):

AMP does not recognise the width & height of your device and serve the mobile page it is depend upon canonical link

**if you have only amp page?**

```
<link rel="canonical" ref="https://www.example.com/your-amp-content-page.html">
```

**if you have both amp and non amp pages?**

*Non AMP Pages*

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/your-amp-content-page.html">
```

*AMP Pages*

```
<link rel="canonical" ref="https://www.example.com/your-non-amp-content-page.html">
```

For more information [**Click Here**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/discovery)